# Can you implement IEnumerable .Contains compatibility for your class?

Tags: .net

If for example, I have a class called "Banana" and I make a list of its instances, say "Bananas" then when I call Bananas.Contains(< some instance of Banana >) It checks if the banana list contains the same reference.

Is it possible to make it check for the value instead though (whatever I might designate as the value to compare)? Sort of like it works with list(of String)?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using. Have you considered using LINQ to query your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` to compare by value.